# Python IF condition is not satisfy but it enter the script. Numpy any() and all() issue

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, if-statement

I have this condition for staring an if, and I think it is starting when not expected, maybe one of you could point me my error or advice a better approach

This is the part of the script:

I obtain values for some angles and assign them  to T2, then at some point I compare

```
...
if 0 <= np.any(T2[i:]) < 0.5*np.pi:
 Do something
```

The values in that array do not satisfy the condition, but it enter in the conditional anyway and I do not know why

Checking in the console I get:

```
In [10]: T2
Out[10]: array([ 1.84103563,  2.68108542,  2.73258615,  2.7358088 ,  2.76608758,
    2.8106091 ])
In [10]: 0 <= np.any(T2) < 0.5*np.pi
Out[10]: True
```

Another evaluation output:

```
In [15]: np.degrees(T2) < 10
Out[15]: array([False, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)

In [16]: np.any(np.degrees(T2)) < 10
Out[16]: True
```

So I guess it is a problem with the use of **.any**/**.all**

Before posting I finally check:

```
In [27]: np.degrees(np.all(T2[i:]))
Out[27]: 57.281
```

Where came the value that is being assigned to the array? How do you avoid that?
Is any other way to do conditionals with arrays?

Comment: Try np.any(T2[(0 <= T2) & (T2 < 0.5 * np.pi)]), I'll explain if it works as expected.

Comment: That was fast :D, It actually work as expected; please explain how **.any()** work. Thank you @FabienP

Comment: Just posted an answer to explain.

Answer (score 2):

This is simply not how Python works:

```
if 0 <= np.any(T2[i:]) < 0.5*np.pi:
```

gets evaluated in this order:

```
if ( 0 <= np.any(T2[i:]) ) < 0.5*np.pi
                  first
           ~~ second ~~
     ~~~~~~ third ~~~~~~
                             ~ fourth ~
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ fifth ~~~~~~
```

So, first the `[]` operator generates a slicing of `T2`, i.e. something that you can iterate through (`first`).

Then, the `any` function checks whether any of these values is not False (ie. not equal to zero). That will return *a single **boolean***, i.e. either `True` or `False`. (`second`)

Since `True` is `>0` and `False == 0`, your first comparison is always `True` (`third`). You could as well just write

```
if True < 0.5*np.pi:
```

Now, `True`, when compared to a numerical value, gets converted to `1`. So, your overall statement is identical to

```
if 1 < 0.5*np.pi:
```

which is **always** the case.

So, no matter what you expected, Python will **always** execute what you enclosed in that `if`, because you explicitly asked it to do so. Python can't guess what you've *meant* with

```
0 <= np.any(T2[i:]) < 0.5*np.pi
```

and honestly, I wouldn't have guessed what you meant, either.

Comment: Ok, very helpful, thank you for the quick answer. I was trying to determine if _any_ of the angles in the array was between 0 and PI/2 but I guess I did all wrong.

Comment: maybe `if any( np.logical_and(0 <= T2[i:], T2[i:] < 0.5*np.pi) )` ?

Comment: or, also elegant `if any( T2[i:] == np.clip(T2[i:] , 0, 0.5*np.pi) ):`

Comment: Wow, so simple! Thank you so much for the help, I have never used **.clip()** or **.any()**. You saved me like hours of researching/coding

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in other answers, `np.any` and `np.all` will reduce the array to a single `bool` (if you do not use the `axis` argument).

It actually tells you if any (or all) values in the array will match the condition `bool(value) == True`.

What you want to do is actually to evaluate if any value from `T2` matches `0 <= T2 < 0.5 * np.pi`.
To achieve this you should evaluate `np.any` on the combination of `0 <= T2` and `T2 < 0.5 * np.pi`

```
In [7]: T2                                       # Your array
Out[7]:
array([ 1.84103563,  2.68108542,  2.73258615,  2.7358088 ,  2.76608758,
        2.8106091 ])

In [8]: (0 <= T2)                                # First condition
Out[8]: array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)

In [9]: (T2 < 0.5 * np.pi)                       # Second condition
Out[9]: array([False, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)

In [10]: (0 <= T2) & (T2 < 0.5 * np.pi)          # Combination of the conditions
Out[10]: array([False, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)

In [11]: np.any((0 <= T2) & (T2 < 0.5 * np.pi))  # Use `any` of the combination
Out[11]: False
```

Each condition produces a `bool` array with the size of `T2`, checking if condition is `True` element-wise.
And the combination uses logical AND to verify that both conditions are `True` element-wise.

Last, `np.any` checks if any value of the combined conditions is `True`. Which is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. The only issue I found is that if one value from the array is True in both, at the end it turned to True because `(0 <= T2) & (T2 < 0.5 * np.pi)` add the values, and does not change if I use **.all()** or **.any()**.

Comment: @JVargas , yes, it is the intended behavior, that value would be in the interval `0 <= T2 < 0.5 * np.pi` and lead to `True`. If you want to check whether at least one value is `False` you should use `not all`, and if you want to check whether all values are `False` (no value is `True`) you should use `not any`.

Answer (score -1):

From the documentation, np.any([-1, 0, 5]) returns True. So, you are basically comparing True with 0 and 0.5*np.pi which causes the condition to be true.